# Must the Owner of a File Have Equal or Greater Permissions than the Group?

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts, samba

**Note:** These results were altered to disguise the real names of these files and user names.

I'm editing the text file `tablet.css` over a Samba Share with the following permissions:

**File Permissions on Server:**

```
root@host:/# /srv/sites/onetwothree.domain/css# ls -l

-rw-rw---- 1 alice devteam 10KiB Dec  4 12:50 normal.css
-r--rw---- 1 alice devteam  5KiB Dec  3 12:10 tablet.css
-r--rw---- 1 alice devteam  4KiB Dec  3 12:15 phone.css
```

**Directory (Folder) Permissions on Server:**

```
dr-xrwx--- 2 alice devteam 4KiB Dec 15 15:09 css
```

I connect to the share via the user `bob` whom is a member of `devteam`.

Given my current understanding of [file permissions](http://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html), I should be able to have write access to the `tablet.css` file. But according to Samba's view, I don't...

**Samba Client's View:**

```
bob@host:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=Galileo,share=alice/sites/onetwothree.domain$ ls -l

-rwx------ 1 bob bob 10KiB Dec  4 12:50 normal.css
-r-x------ 1 bob bob  5KiB Dec  3 12:10 tablet.css
-r-x------ 1 bob bob  4KiB Dec  3 12:15 phone.css
```

Interestingly enough, although opening `tablet.css` with `nano` warns me about missing write permissions, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> seems to works just fine; announcing it saved correctly. I can verify though that indeed on the server side that the changes were never written.

One of the workarounds I made was to simply give write permissions to the owner (as can be seen by `normal.css` ), and that fixes the issue. But what if I don't want to give the current owner those write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to ensure the group `devteam` has the only write permissions to those files, then perhaps one of the members of `devteam`, in your case `bob`, should be the owner of those files instead of `alice`...